# Installing & using the Android NDK in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-ndk, installation

I've been running the Android SDK for a while now in Eclipse (MAC OSX). I've downloaded the NDK and installed the C/C++ tools in Eclipse, but could anyone guide me on using the NDK? For example, do I just create an Android project like normal and build it with the NDK instead?

Really could do with a decent tutorial if anyone know of any.

EDIT: OK so I have the NDK installed now (I think) but does anyone have any idea how to use it? I got as far as this (taken from [here](http://sseyod.blogspot.com/2009/08/android-jnindk-notes-on-getting-started.html)):

> Run Terminal
>
> cd ~/android-ndk-1.5_r1
>
> make APP=hello-jni

In order to run the hello-jni sample application, but I get an error in terminal saying:

> Android NDK:  APP variable defined to
>   unknown applications: hellojni
>   Android NDK:  You might want to use
>   one of the following:
>   build/core/main.mk:81: *** Android
>   NDK:  Aborting    .  Stop.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Good question.  I need to use the NDK for a project I'm working on now, and there's not much good information out there.

Comment: Yea, I havent got much time left today but if I work it out I'll update here...

Comment: Here is an excellent tutorial. **[How to set up and use the NDK](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html)** Eclipse is not much help when it comes to the NDK I'm afraid

Comment: [Tutorial: Using Eclipse for NDK projects](http://codemaemo.appforce.org/2010/07/tutorial-using-eclipse-for-ndk-projects/)

Comment: Eclipse is in fact in great help when developing NDK applications. This tutorial is outdated, better look into the latest NDK

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the info, I didn't know tat was possible in Eclipse

Comment: Any help with the end bit, "Now create the Android.mk file in jni directory and start coding and building native Android code in Eclipse!"?

Comment: This tutorial covers only setting up Eclipse to work with NDK projects. Using NDK itself is another topic and is documented in the download package from Android's website

Comment: I followed this guide and never got it to work properly, seems there is something missing in the setup at least for my system. I had better success with this:  http://www.rbgrn.net/content/348-get-your-eclipse-integrated-ndk-on

Comment: I have written a step by step tutorial here. http://www.permadi.com/blog/2011/09/setting-up-android-jni-projects-in-windows-eclipse-and-sequoyah/ Hope it helps.

Comment: @ognian your link is broken please update it

Comment: this links is not working anybody has found another link for same content???

Comment: Latest version (yearr: 2016) [tutorial here](http://artichowicz.net/2016/03/18/how-to-set-up-android-ndk-and-run-hellojni-on-windows/).

Answer (score 24):

As simply as I can describe it, building an Android app from within Eclipse that uses the NDK requires two steps.

First, inside your terminal you need to run the NDK build script on your project. cd into the root of your project directory and then execute the ndk-build script within that directory.

For example:

```
cd ~/workspace/hello-jni
./~/android-ndk-1.5_r1/ndk-build
```

After doing this, you should see some output that results in the creation of a *.SO file within the obj directory within your project directory.

Once you have the *.SO file, the final step to building an application with the Android NDK through Eclipse is to build it with Eclipse like you would any other application and then deploy it for testing.

If you make any changes to the C/C++ code you'll need to repeat step one and regenerate your *.SO file before building and deploying your application from within Eclipse again.

I would like to note that by using the Android NDK your android apps are still based upon Java. They're just communicating with code written in C/C++ by way of the [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

Finally, I am not aware of any Eclipse plugins that will aid with NDK development. Everything I know about the NDK I have learned the official [Android NDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html). Please feel free to comment and let me know if there anything I can clear up in my response.

Comment: Hey thanks, I wrote this question a couple of years ago and never really looked into it so I'll give this a go in a couple of days or so. Thanks +1

Comment: Thanks... I've seen so many conflicting answrs and this one did it for me.

Comment: The information in this answer is out of date. As @HamidFadishei pointed out below, there is now an eclipse plugin that adds in NDK support.

Answer (score 12):

Native development and debugging support came into Eclipse environment as of ADT version 20. http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin

- Set path to NDK from Eclipse Preferences -> Android -> NDK
- Right-click on your project and choose Android Tools -> Add Native Support

developer.android.com states you also need Cygwin.

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Contents

Required development tools

- For all development platforms, GNU Make 3.81 or later is required. Earlier versions of GNU Make might work but have not been tested.
- A recent version of awk (either GNU Awk or Nawk) is also required.
- For Windows, Cygwin 1.7 or higher is required. The NDK will not work with Cygwin 1.5 installations.

Comment: I totally missed this - thanx for the heads up!

Answer (score 5):

The docs directory in the NDK has some pretty good information on how to use the NDK itself. Read the overview, Application.mk, and Android.mk HTML docs. You'll want to google for the Sun JNI PDF, download it, and learn what JNI is all about before you go any further. This is because simply compiling a bunch of C/C++ code into libraries with the NDK is only part of the process. You have to write native Java code that calls your C/C++, and you have to create wrapper functions in C/C++ that adhere to JNI conventions that the native Java code can invoke. JNI has been around a long time, it's not Android specific by any means. So, you can, to learn about it, go quite far following tutorials geared towards JNI, using command line tools like javah and javac, and then return to integrating with the NDK after you know the basics. (For an example of what these C shims look like, take a look at the hello-jni sample in the NDK; the C source file there shows you typically what the shims look like. Using javah to generate these shims is the way to go, you create Java classes that have native methods, process them with javah, and it generates the C headers for you, then you code up C functions that adhere to the generated function prototypes).

Note: while the NDK docs would have you manually building from command line and then going into Eclipse to build your app (a laborious sequence of steps, to be sure, especially if you are changing the C/C++ code), it turns out you can integrate easily with Eclipse so that the NDK is run each time you build from Eclipse. To see how, [read here](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/ndk-builder-in-eclipse/).

Answer (score 3):

This is for benefit of others who want to create the project from scratch from within eclipse: I followed steps mentioned here in this blog here and it works fine: http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/

Answer (score 1):

To attempt to answer the question directly - you need to run ndk-build in the folder with the native code within your project folder.  This creates the .so files found in the file explorer/resources tree under jni in Eclipse.  These functions, if the syntax in the code is correct, can now be called from your java code.

I found many sources of help when install and getting to grips with Android Developer Tools and the NDK.  I wrote a [blog post](http://workingmatt.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/set-up-android-sdk-and-ndk.html) to share my experiences and hopefully give back to the community that helped me get there which may help understand my answer: http://workingmatt.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/set-up-android-sdk-and-ndk.html