# Configuring and Using NDK in eclipse on mac os Lion

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, native

I am right now configuring ndk in eclipse on mac lion os. i downloaded Eclipse 3.5, android sdk & ndk r7b. can anyone give me the procedure to configure the NDK in eclipse for native android application development?

Comment: [this][1] may help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3469448/1289716

Comment: hi mac, its for windows only. am in need of instructions for mac setup.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky to set up right on OSX but I've done it (on Lion, not sure about others) so it is possible.

Download the OSX bzip [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) and follow the instructions 'Installing the NDK' and 'Getting Started with the NDK'.  From there try to build the the `hello-jni` sample, found [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#samples).  I installed the APK it produced on the android emulator and it worked fine, same for some of the other samples.

I did it without using eclipse, but from what I understand the eclipse plugin is just a wrapper for the `android` and `adb` binaries.