# Do I need to install NDK to build OpenCV Android projects?

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to compile OpenCV's sample Android projects, but am facing a difficulty. I get this error:
 Program "ndk-build.cmd" not found in PATH

The projects that use NDK C/C++ do not compile. All others compile successfully. I tried to fix the issue by editing the C/C++ Build Environment and the GNU C++ Includes. Both of these did not work. I don't think I'm doing this right. I am using Windows 7 for Android Development. An online forum suggested adding a path that includes ../android-ndk-r8/.. but this "android-ndk-r8" directory doesn't exist in OpenCV-2.4.2-android-sdk and I cannot find something thats equivalent.

I've been trying to fix this for a week but to no gain. Its really frustrating to not be able to get down to coding. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: have you downloaded [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) to build you native library?

Comment: I have installed the NDK but don't know what to add to the PATH

Answer (score 0):

Have u installed the android ndk bundle rom android ??? android-ndk-r8 can be downloaded at the below location

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

You have download ndk package from android to work with c/c++ code. OpenCv will not contain ndk package.

-Preeya

Answer (score 0):

i Would like you to take look on the Following [Link](http://sseyod.blogspot.com/2009/08/android-jnindk-notes-on-getting-started.html) and [Stack Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469448/installing-using-the-android-ndk-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you haven't specified the `PATH`. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14527852/1446598) answer would help.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project -> go to project properties -> Go to C/C++ build -> Build Variables -> Add your environment variable named NDKROOT (Name) with the relevant path (Value) (Exactly where your NDK is there). 
Note that you need to repeat this per NDK project.